# A girl accepting Islam, getting married to a Muslim man, all of her family is non-muslim Wali issue

Tags: wali, interfaith-marriage

Dear brother and sisters. I met a girl abroad, who is not a Muslimah. She is willing to accept Islam and I want to do nikkah with her to save myself from committing zina. Nikkah is only for the sake of ALLAH and to save me, my soul from Jahannum.

I travel abroad frequently for my business and it is harder to live longer time period without a wife.

All of her family is non-muslim and they preach Christianity. Thus, they will never agree and she is even scared to ask her family if she can become a Muslimah and get married to a Muslim man.

She will not have a wali from her family for sure. That is almost 100%  closer to impossible.

I have 2 friends, with a good character and I can arrange an Imam from Masjid to do nikkah with her after she do her Shahadah. I will write the Nikkah conditions on the paper and I will sign, she will sign, 2 Muslim men will sign and Masjid Imam will sign.

I will give her mahr at the time of Nikkah.

So, the Nikkah will be announced and I pray to ALLAH to forgive if anything is not right and make her halal for me through Nikkah.

Our intentions are good and we will do everything possible according to Islam.

Please advice my brothers and sisters if I'm doing anything wrong or if I need to do something extra.

May ALLAH guide us all and forgive our sins and may ALLAH give reward to those who advice. Thanks

Comment: The wali of a Muslim must be a Muslim. If none of her family is Muslim then the Islamic ruler can be her wali, and if one is not available then she can either be married without a wali as in the Hanafi madhab or by appointing any local community leader or really any Muslim as her wali.

Answer (score 0):

If a virgin girl is Muslim and her father and  grandfather  are not Muslim, she can marry without needing permission from them. because a non-Muslin can not have Wilayah (guardianship or ولایت) on a Muslim. But if a virgin girl is not Muslim and her father is also not Muslim, then the permission of the father is needed for marriage. Considering that a Muslim man can marry a non-Muslim woman only if the marriage is a temporary marriage (متعه).

[Referenec](http://www.imam-khomeini.ir/fa/c12_20508/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7_%D9%BE%D8%AF%D8%B1_%D9%88_%D8%AC%D8%AF_%D9%BE%D8%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C_%D8%BA%DB%8C%D8%B1_%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86_%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%B2_%D8%A8%D8%B1_%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF_%D8%AE%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B4_%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA_%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF_%D9%88_%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC_%D9%85%D9%88%D9%82%D8%AA_%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF_%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%A8%D8%A7_%D8%AF%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B1_%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%84_%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D8%A7_%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%87_%D9%BE%D8%AF%D8%B1_%D8%AF%D8%AE%20...)

Answer (score -3):

In Islam, the marriage contract is considered to be a legal agreement between two consenting adults, and it is important that both parties are fully aware of the terms and conditions of the contract. If a Muslim man wishes to marry a former Christian woman or yet to be Muslim who does not have a wali, there are several steps that can be taken to ensure that the marriage is conducted in accordance with Islamic law.

Firstly, the couple should seek the advice of a qualified Islamic scholar or imam who can provide guidance on the matter. **The imam can act as the woman's wali for the purpose of the marriage contract,** and can help to ensure that all of the necessary conditions are met.

Secondly, the couple should ensure that they are both fully aware of the rights and responsibilities that come with marriage in Islam ³. This includes the obligation to treat each other with kindness and respect, and to work together to build a strong and healthy relationship.

Finally, the couple should seek the blessings of their families and communities, and should strive to build a strong and supportive network of friends and loved ones who can help them to navigate the challenges of married life.

May Allah bless you and guide you to the right path.